# Encode Video from Bitmap Frames one at a time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ffmpeg, bitmap, video-encoding

I have been looking into this for about an hour only being able to find how to encode a video once you have all the frames of a video. However this is using way too much ram. I discovered something called a Sink Writer but the only somewhat reproducible tutorial I could find was for c++ and would be very difficult to implement anyway.

The question is, with c# how could I encode a video one frame at a time without needing to have all the frames at once using ffmpeg or another encoder. (I get a frame, encode it and then free the memory before getting another frame). And then be able to save the video to a file when I am done. I also would like the ability to save audio samples to the video if possible

The bitmap frames are in the format of a `byte[]` with each pixel being stored by 3 bytes (one for each color) but I can convert the format if needed

Comment: Are you calling ffmpeg or are you calling libav functions yourself?

Comment: @kesh I was previously using ffmpeg to convert a raw video file created from the frames to mp4

Comment: If you already have FFmpeg commadn figured out to write your frame data to, then all you need to do is to write incrementally to the [stdin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput?view=net-6.0) of the ffmpeg process. You should be able to do just `myStreamWriter.Write(frame_bytes);` each time you have a frame ready. (I don't know C# myself, but this is the idea)